# Configure IoC Container in hybrid ASP.NET WebForms MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, structuremap

How is a hybrid ASP.NET WebForms / ASP.NET MVC supposed to configure an IoC container, such as StructureMap?  For example, if I was to apply StructureMap to an ASP.NET MVC app, I'd simply use the Dependency Resolver in ASP.NET MVC and I'd be all set.  And in an ASP.NET WebForms app, I would use the BuildUp(this) feature of StructureMap in some sort of Base Page class that UI.Page would extend or use Global.asax.  But what would you do in the case of a hybrid application?  How would something like this look?  Would I use global.asax for both in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're answering your own question:

- In Web Forms, use the build up functionality (for example you can have a base Page class and a base User control class. Don't forget this one)
- In MVC, you can use the dependency resolver.

There's no problem using both at the same time on a hybrid web application.

There are other techniques for web pages that involve handlers. An interesting article:

- [Inversion of control and dependency injection with Web Forms in 2 acts](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/ioc_and_di_with_web_forms)